# Find information about host/user by his public key?

Tags: ssh, user-tracking

Say, I was reviewing my log files and noticed that someone with certain public key tried to connect to my server and got access denied (because his public key is not in my `authorized_keys` file).

May I somehow gather more information about user/host with this associated public keys? For example, this key may be attached to Github profile and I can filter Github users by public keys and find the one that used to attempt to login into my server?

Thanks!

Comment: This has been done: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10004678

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, if the user sends a public key. You can use a [tweaked SSH server](https://github.com/FiloSottile/whoami.filippo.io) to grab the public key, and check it against whatever database or API you like. Problem is, you probably be able to use this as a real SSH server, so you'll probably want to move your real service to a different port.

Even if the key isn't available through some API to identify the user, the comment after the key may contain clues (e.g. `skiddie@l337machin3`). **Edit:** actually, I doubt that this field is sent to the server at all, but I'd have to check. In that case, this can be ignored.

Also, unless the attacker is unskilled, I doubt they would be using their personal keys for attacking random hosts.

Comment: Dat `1337`...
That's interesting, thanks for sharing!
Do you know any other widely used services which I can enumerate for public key?